# How to run adev(aiohttp_devtools) command using PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, aiohttp

I want to use PyCharm debugger with aiohttp_devtools, but have no idea how to run command:

```
adev runserver --no-livereload
```

in this window
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for raising the question.

Right now there is no easy way to do it.

The only solution is creating own custom startup script which instantiates dev server like `from aiohttp_devtools import cli; cli()`.

But I've created an issue for your needs: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp-devtools/issues/99

Comment: Thank you. I tried to create own script but getting `RuntimeError: context has already been set`
Error traceback: https://gist.github.com/comalex/a7dc70e73973a2cc961a2b4809daf5b2 
Somehow my script calling itself two times.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use PyCharm and don't know its magic.

Let's assume you have `manage.py` with content `from aiohttp_devtools.cli import cli; cli()`

`python3 manage.py -V` should print version, `python3 manage.py runserver` starts a server.

Is it true for your environment?

Comment: Yes, `python3 manage.py -V` shows version. But the error isn't related with Pycharm (I tried that in shell as well) and not related with my app( I tried server  example from aiohttp doc).

Comment: I put `manage.py` to the script filed, `runserver` and options to the script parameters filed. But see http://prntscr.com/fpxkw7 in console same issue

Answer (score 3):

Add a new file to run the CLI and reference that in the debug setup:

`adev.py`:

```py
from aiohttp_devtools.cli import cli

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Then reference that to setup debugging:

[image: pycharm debug]

With that everything worked fine for me.

#### Context:

I've fixed the issue above referenced by Andrew #99 and will create a new release `v0.5.0`, however that doesn't actually fix the problem here. I'll explain how to get debug working below.

I do use pycharm, but I steer clear of debug and similar features: partly because (as in this case) they're generally not worth the effort, and partly so when someone comes up with a decent opensource or paid IDE for python I can get away from pycharm's awful bugginess and awful customer service without much hassle.

The thing to remember when wrestling with pycharm is it was built by java developers in a hurry, not python developers; so it often deviates significantly from the pythonic way of doing things.

For example, in this case the developer clearly hadn't heard about `python -m` "run module as a script" or the virtualenv `env/bin` extension to `$PATH`.

Comment: Thank you, that exactly what @andrew-svetlov suggested, but we missed `if __name__ == '__main__':`, now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to setup debug configuration with 'Module name' instead of 'Script path' and external `adev.py` script:

[image]

Also, you may need to set proper 'Working directory' and `PYTHONPATH` (mark directories as *sources roots* for that).