# How do I use aiohttp-devtools with the PyCharm debugger?

Tags: python, pycharm, aiohttp

I'm working on a team where we're using [aiohttp-devtools](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp-devtools) to run a local server on our computers while developing a website.

I'm now in a situation where I'd like to use the PyCharm debugger, but it isn't working (I'm setting breakpoints, but the code isn't stopping at those breakpoints).

I came across [this SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44820398/how-to-run-adevaiohttp-devtools-command-using-pycharm) but I'm not sure it applies to my situation.

Here's what my run configuration looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being to use [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44860530/4115031) posted in [the Stack Overflow question I linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44820398/4115031) in my question:

Create a new file with the code below and have PyCharm run that file in debug mode:

```
from aiohttp_devtools.cli import cli

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```